# Jetpack Compose: How to change theme from light to dark mode programmatically onClick

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

TL;DR change the theme and recompose the app between light and dark themes onClick.

Hello! I have an interesting issue I have been struggling to figure out and would love some help. I am trying to implement a settings screen which lets the user change the theme of the app (selecting Dark, Light, or Auto which matches system setting).

I am successfully setting the theme **dynamically** via invoking the **isSystemInDarkTheme()** function when choosing the color palette, but am struggling to **recompose** the app between light and dark themes on the click of a button.

My strategy now is to create a theme model which hoists the state from the settings component which the user actually chooses the theme in. This theme model then exposes a theme state variable to the custom theme (wrapped around material theme) to decide whether to pick the light or dark color palette. Here is the relevant code -->

Theme

```
@Composable
fun CustomTheme(
themeViewModel: ThemeViewModel = viewModel(),
content: @Composable() () -> Unit,
) {
   val colors = when (themeViewModel.theme.value.toString()) {
       "Dark" -> DarkColorPalette
       "Light" -> LightColorPalette
       else -> if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) DarkColorPalette else LightColorPalette
   }

   MaterialTheme(
       colors = colors,
       typography = typography,
       shapes = shapes,
       content = content
   )
   }
```

Theme model and state variable

```
class ThemeViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val _theme = MutableLiveData("Auto")
val theme: LiveData<String> = _theme

fun onThemeChanged(newTheme: String) {
    when (newTheme) {
        "Auto" -> _theme.value = "Light"
        "Light" -> _theme.value = "Dark"
        "Dark" -> _theme.value = "Auto"
    }
}
}
```

Component (UI) code

```
@Composable
fun Settings(
   themeViewModel: ThemeViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
   ...
   val theme: String by themeViewModel.theme.observeAsState("")
   ...
   ScrollableColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
       Column {
        ...
        Card() {
            Row() {
                Text(text = theme,
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable(
                        onClick = {
                            themeViewModel.onThemeChanged(theme)
                        }
                    )
                )
            }
        }
   }
```

Thanks so much for your time and help! ***I have elided some code here in the UI component, it is possible I have left out some closure syntax in the process.

Comment: Where do yo apply your theme?

Comment: I apply my theme in the MainActivity, wrapping it around the main Composable like the boilerplate compose project sets up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One possibility, shown in the [Jetpack theming codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-theming#3), is to set the darkmode via input parameter, which ensures the theme will be recomposed when the parameter changes:

```
@Composable
fun CustomTheme(
  darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
  content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
  MaterialTheme(
    colors = if (darkTheme) DarkColors else LightColors,
    content = content
  )
}
```

In your mainActivity you can observe changes to your viewModel and pass them down to your customTheme:

```
val darkTheme = themeViewModel.darkTheme.observeAsState(initial = true)

CustomTheme(darkTheme.value){
//yourContent
}
```

This way your compose previews can simply be styled in dark theme:

```
@Composable
private fun DarkPreview() {
    CustomTheme(darkTheme = true) {
        content
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the changes are being observed correctly, I can tell because when I switch the system setting from light to dark theme, the app responds. What I can't figure out is how to switch the theme from dark to light on the click of a button.

Comment: You are observing the theme changes in your Settings composable, but not in your CustomTheme: `val colors = when (themeViewModel.theme.value.toString())`, hence they are not applied to your theme

Comment: Even when I observe the changes in the custom theme, the app does not recompose when the theme is changed onclick. Your suggestion is not working but thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same viewModel instance?

Answer (score 7):

Based on [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme), the official way to [handle theme changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#change-themes) triggered by a user's action (ie. choice of a theme other than the system one through a custom built setting) is to use

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()
```

This call alone will take care of most things, including restarting any activity (thus, recomposing). For this to work, we need:

- The Activity which calls `setContent` to extend `AppCompatActvity`
- The user's choice to be persisted and applied at each start of the app (through `AppCompatDelegate`)
- To define whether dark mode is enabled, your `CustomTheme` should also consider the value of the user's `defaultNightMode` preference:

```
@Composable
fun CustomTheme(
  isDark: Boolean = isNightMode(),
  content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
  MaterialTheme(
    colors = if (darkTheme) DarkColors else LightColors,
    content = content
  )
}

@Composable
private fun isNightMode() = when (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()) {
    AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO -> false
    AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES -> true
    else -> isSystemInDarkTheme()
}
```

this is nice to have as it avoids the need to get this value in an Activity just to pass it to the theme with `CustomTheme(isDark = isDark)`.

[This article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94) goes through all of the above providing more details.

Answer (score 6):

In case you want a button/switch to change the theme and make it persistent as setting, you can also achieve this by using [Jetpack DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) (recommended) or [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences), get your theme state in MainActivity and pass it to your Theme composable, and wherever you want to modify it.

You can find a complete working example with `SharedPreferences` in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/stefanosansone/compose-theme-switcher).

This example is using a `Singleton` and [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) for dependencies and is valid for all the preferences you want store.

Comment: The GitHub repo is no longer available :(

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the recommended way, but one option is to use the [recreate method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#recreate()) (available since API level 11).

In order to use it outside of the activity and within your composable, you could pass the function call. Taking your code as a basis

```
class SomeActivity {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        setContent {
            ...
            themeViewModel.onRecreate = { recreate() }

            CustomTheme(themeViewModel) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your viewModel

```
class ThemeViewModel: ViewModel() {

    lateinit var onRecreate: () -> Unit

    private val _theme = MutableLiveData("Auto")
    val theme: LiveData<String> = _theme
    
    fun onThemeChanged(newTheme: String) {
        when (newTheme) {
            "Auto" -> _theme.value = "Light"
            "Light" -> _theme.value = "Dark"
            "Dark" -> _theme.value = "Auto"
        }
        onRecreate
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just made it working with a simple model.
Here is how you do it.

Declare a public variable isUiModeDark

```
lateinit var isUiModeDark : MutableState<Boolean?>
```

Then, inside your theme's Lambda:

```
isUiModeIsDark = remember { mutableStateOf(userSelectedThemeIsNight(context)) }
val colorScheme = when (isUiModeIsDark.value) {
    true -> DarkColorScheme
    false -> LightColorScheme
    else -> if (systemTheme) DarkColorScheme else LightColorScheme
}
.
.
.
MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme = colorScheme,
    content = content
)
```

Now how to call recomposition? Simple, just change the value of isUiModeDark in your settings.

- true means dark theme app override is selected
- false means light theme app override is selected
- null means No theme app override is selected and system theme is followed.

As to why this works just read the docs on MutableState and remember. Basically
any change in MutableStates value causes recomposition. Neither Live data nor any other alternatives work until or unless they are derivates of the type State. The composable is basically just subscribed to the changes made to MutableState or any derivates of the State class.

Comment: Here systemTheme is just a parameter that stores the output of isSystemInDarkTheme().