# Understanding Compose Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I've been delving into **Jetbrains Compose** for the past few days, building on my experience with **Jetpack Compose** where I've created several apps (check out this link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prime.player). Despite consulting the official docs, I still have a few questions that I'd appreciate answers to.

1. **Jetbrains Compose Plugin Requirement:**

   - Do we need a plugin for Jetbrains Compose?
   - In my exploration, it seems unlike Jetpack Compose, Jetbrains Compose doesn't require a specific plugin. Am I overlooking anything?
2. **Consistency in Compose UI Dependencies:**

   - Are the dependencies, especially Compose UI, consistent between Jetpack Compose and Jetbrains Compose?
   - My observation from inspecting the generated template suggests that the imports in `commonMain` are Android-specific.
3. **Compatibility with 3rd Party Libraries in Compose Multiplatform:**

   - If Compose UI is the same, why can't we use Jetpack Compose 3rd party libraries in Compose Multiplatform?
4. **CommonMain and Android-specific Features:**

   - I noticed that `commonMain` can call the `blur` modifier, which internally relies on the Android SDK. Is this feature rebuilt for Jetbrains Compose, or are they essentially the same?

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose: How to change theme from light to dark mode programmatically onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65192409/jetpack-compose-how-to-change-theme-from-light-to-dark-mode-programmatically-on)

Comment: Why do you think Jetpack compose would require you to extend `ComponentActivity`? It is completely fine to use compose in an Activity that extends `AppCompatActivity`